# Why do I get a NoSuchFieldError exception in Java?

Tags: java, exception, browser, web

I'm trying to display any website using Eclipse internal browser.

Here's the code I'm trying:

```
public class WebTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NativeInterface.open();
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("YouTube Viewer");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.getContentPane().add(getBrowserPanel(),
                        BorderLayout.CENTER);
                frame.setSize(800, 600);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        NativeInterface.runEventPump();
        // don't forget to properly close native components
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NativeInterface.close();
            }
        }));
    }

    public static JPanel getBrowserPanel() {
        JPanel webBrowserPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JWebBrowser webBrowser = new JWebBrowser();
        webBrowserPanel.add(webBrowser, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        webBrowser.setBarsVisible(false);
        webBrowser.navigate("https://www.youtube.com/v/b-Cr0EWwaTk?fs=1");
        return webBrowserPanel;
    }
}
```

However, when I try to run it, I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEPENDENCIES_CHECKVERSIONS
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NSSystemPropertySWT.<clinit>(NSSystemPropertySWT.java:94)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.core.SWTNativeInterface.<clinit>(SWTNativeInterface.java:86)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.internal.NativeCoreObjectFactory.create(NativeCoreObjectFactory.java:38)
at chrriis.dj.nativeswing.swtimpl.NativeInterface.<clinit>(NativeInterface.java:22)
at WebTest.main(WebTest.java:14)
```

So there is clearly something wrong with my dependencies... But I'm not sure how do I fix this, I have included all necessary jars:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: The log says that your DJ Native Swing library doesn't have the field `DEPENDENCIES_CHECKVERSIONS`. Try to update this dependency

Answer (score 0):

maybe this help with your problem, the oficial forum of dj proyect

http://ehc.ac/p/djproject/discussion/671154/thread/44d88f52/

Comment: None of this is helping, actually. I tried various versions of this lib.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar problem as yours, the problem was with jar files [ ***DJNativeSwing.jar*** & ***dj-nativeswing-swt-1.0.2.jar***] which I replaced with jars that came with DJ project.

Download DJ project from [sourceforge_dj_project](http://sourceforge.net/projects/djproject/files/DJ%20Native%20Swing/1.0.2/DJNativeSwing-SWT-1-0-2.zip/download?use_mirror=skylineservers&r=http%3A%2F%2Fehc.ac%2Fprojects%2Fdjproject%2F&use_mirror=skylineservers).
Extract and copy jars [**DJNativeSwing.jar** & **DJNativeSwing-SWT.jar**] and replace with previous ones in your project.

**DJNATIVESWING-SWT-1-0-2** extracted folder contents: 
[image: DJNATIVESWING-SWT-1-0-2-Contents]